# draw line inside Moviclip in ActionScript3

Tags: actionscript-3, line, draw

I am wondering how to draw line inside movieclip[] array:

```
movieclip myted
    line       myshape
        for (var i:int = 0; i < myted.numChildren-1; i++) {
        if (myted.getChildAt(i).hitTestPoint(mouseX,mouseY,true)) {


            //drawingLine.transform.colorTransform=pal_color;

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

All drawing that you do with a Graphics instance is based on basic drawing with lines and curves. Consequently, all ActionScript drawing must be performed using the same series of steps:

- Define line and fill styles
- Set the initial drawing position
- Draw lines, curves, and shapes (optionally moving the drawing point)
- If necessary, finish creating a fill

to define a line and fill styles:

```
var myShape:Shape = new Shape();
myShape.graphics.lineStyle(2, 0x990000, .75);
myShape.graphics.moveTo(100, 100); 
myShape.graphics.lineTo(200, 200);

movieClipInstanceName.addChild(myShape);
```

Answer (score 0):

" https://i.stack.imgur.com/ESfzi.png  "
Thanks
no understand not working ?
not work raw line inside movieclip!
drawing line inside movieclip S1 .. s27 when mouse move inside teddy
////////////////

```
 var drawingLine:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
s.addChild(drawingLine);

//2.
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, MouseDown);
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, MouseUp);

//3.
function MouseDown(event:MouseEvent):void{
drawingLine.graphics.lineStyle(3);
drawingLine.graphics.moveTo(mouseX, mouseY);
s.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, MouseMove);
}

//4.
function MouseMove(event:MouseEvent):void{
drawingLine.graphics.lineTo(mouseX, mouseY);
            for (var i:int = 0; i < teddy.numChildren-1; i++) {
                if (teddy.getChildByName("s"+i).hitTestPoint(mouseX,mouseY,true)) {
                    pal_color=teddy.getChildAt(i).transform.colorTransform;
                    pal_color.color=colors[current_color];
                    teddy.getChildByName("s"+i).transform.colorTransform=pal_color;


                }
            }
}

//5.
function MouseUp(event:MouseEvent):void{
stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, MouseMove);
}

        public function on_teddy_click(e:MouseEvent):void {
            for (var i:int = 0; i < teddy.numChildren-1; i++) {
                if (teddy.getChildByName("s"+i).hitTestPoint(mouseX,mouseY,true)) {
                    pal_color=teddy.getChildAt(i).transform.colorTransform;
                    pal_color.color=colors[current_color];
                    teddy.getChildByName("s"+i).transform.colorTransform=pal_color;


                }
            }

        }

/////////////////////////////////
sample 2:
not Draw line inside movieclip "S"

var drawingLine:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
s.addChild(drawingLine);


stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, MouseDown);
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, MouseUp);


function MouseDown(event:MouseEvent):void{
drawingLine.graphics.lineStyle(3);
drawingLine.graphics.moveTo(mouseX, mouseY);
s.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, MouseMove);
}


function MouseMove(event:MouseEvent):void{
drawingLine.graphics.lineTo(mouseX, mouseY);
}


function MouseUp(event:MouseEvent):void{
stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, MouseMove);
}
```